# Debian + Strongswan: does not pass traffic from the Internet to the tunnel

Tags: debian, iptables, linux-networking, strongswan

I'm trying to setup a remote VPN server to access the internet from my home PC. It is on a leased AWS VPS, with `Debian` and `Strongswan`. It is meant to receive my traffic via the tunnel, forward it to the internet, receive the responses from the internet and forward them back to me via the tunnel. My PC successfully connects to it, it receives my traffic and forwards it to the Internet, but it does not seem to receive responses from the internet, so it does not work as intended. `Iptables` shows the outgoing traffic from the tunnel to the Internet, but zero traffic from the internet:

```
root@internal_aws_ip:/home/admin# iptables -L -nv
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
14667 2284K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
  595 56329 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
    3   168 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
   13  7232 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:500
   35 19992 ACCEPT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            udp dpt:4500
   14  4592 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 8697  522K ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       10.10.10.0/24        0.0.0.0/0            policy match dir in pol ipsec proto 50
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            10.10.10.0/24        policy match dir out pol ipsec proto 50
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 8639 packets, 3433K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

`tcpdump` also shows traffic passing from the tunnel to the internet, but no traffic in reverse direction:

```
root@internal_aws_ip:/home/admin# tcpdump port not ssh
....
06:46:19.605227 IP #HOME_PC#.ipsec-nat-t > #AWS_VPS#.eu-central-1.compute.internal.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xcbf6e396,seq=0x43), length 100
06:46:19.605227 IP ip-10-10-10-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal.50576 > dns.google.domain: 38403+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
06:46:19.605284 IP ip-10-10-10-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal.50576 > dns.google.domain: 38403+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
06:46:20.119576 IP #HOME_PC#.ipsec-nat-t > #AWS_VPS#.eu-central-1.compute.internal.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xcbf6e396,seq=0x44), length 100
06:46:20.119576 IP ip-10-10-10-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal.61302 > dns.google.domain: 42466+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
06:46:20.119634 IP ip-10-10-10-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal.61302 > dns.google.domain: 42466+ A? dns.msftncsi.com. (34)
06:46:20.122526 IP #HOME_PC#.ipsec-nat-t > #AWS_VPS#.eu-central-1.compute.internal.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xcbf6e396,seq=0x45), length 100
06:46:20.122526 IP ip-10-10-10-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal.53026 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [S], seq 2356796043, win 65280, options [mss 1360,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
06:46:20.122580 IP ip-10-10-10-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal.53026 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [S], seq 2356796043, win 65280, options [mss 1320,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
06:46:20.122773 IP #HOME_PC#.ipsec-nat-t > #AWS_VPS#.eu-central-1.compute.internal.ipsec-nat-t: UDP-encap: ESP(spi=0xcbf6e396,seq=0x46), length 100
06:46:20.122773 IP ip-10-10-10-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal.53027 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [S], seq 2988801698, win 65280, options [mss 1360,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
06:46:20.122791 IP ip-10-10-10-1.eu-central-1.compute.internal.53027 > 82.221.107.34.bc.googleusercontent.com.http: Flags [S], seq 2988801698, win 65280, options [mss 1320,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
....
```

IPsec.conf contains

```
config setup
        uniqueids=never
        charondebug="ike 2, knl 2, cfg 3, net 2, esp 2, dmn 2,  mgr 2"

conn %default
        keyexchange=ikev2
        ike=aes128gcm16-sha2_256-prfsha256-ecp256,aes256-sha2_256-prfsha256-modp2048!
        esp=aes128gcm16-sha2_256-ecp256,chacha20poly1305-sha512,aes256gcm16-ecp384,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha1!
        fragmentation=yes
        rekey=no
        compress=yes
        dpdaction=clear
        left=%any
        leftauth=pubkey
        leftsourceip=#SERVER_IP#
        leftid=#SERVER_IP#
        leftcert=debian.pem
        leftsendcert=always
        leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
        right=%any
        rightauth=pubkey
        rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
        rightdns=8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4

conn ikev2-pubkey
        auto=add
```

`sysctl.conf` contains (most of the commented-out lines are not shown)

```
# /etc/sysctl.conf - Configuration file for setting system variables

# Uncomment the next line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# Do not accept ICMP redirects (prevent MITM attacks)
net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects = 0

# Do not send ICMP redirects (we are not a router)
net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects = 0

net.ipv4.ip_no_pmtu_disc = 1
```

The server itself seems to work with the Internet fine, pings both by ip-addresses and by domain names are successful.

Beside the server I'm talking about, I have another similar VPN server on a similar leased AWS VPS. It works fine with another one of my home computers. And I can't find any relevant difference between the two servers' configurations.

I have very little experience with Linux servers. What else should I check to find out the reason? What additional information can shed light on the situation?

UPD: `iptables -t nat -L` replies

```
.... 
Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
ACCEPT     all  --  ip-10-10-10-0.eu-central-1.compute.internal/24  anywhere             policy match dir out pol ipsec  
MASQUERADE  all  --  ip-10-10-10-0.eu-central-1.compute.internal/24  anywhere
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Source NAT / IP masquerade?

Comment: Could you say it in more detail? I am new to Linux administration

Comment: The default gateway that serves your VPS does not know ("correctly") where traffics for `10.10.10.0/24` should go. (At least in usual/simple networking setup, a router/gateway does not keep track of where communication originates from.) So when replies from Internet gets back to the gateway, it will goes back to your VPS (and in turn the VPN clients) only if 1. the gateway has a route that correctly "direct" those replies 2. the original traffics were modifed such that it has the "LAN IP" of the VPS as the source IP (i.e. source NAT; and such modification is tracked by the NAT'ing host).

Comment: Source NAT / IP masquerade can easily be set up with iptables. Do some research on the `SNAT` and `MASQUERADE` target.

Comment: Can't format it properly here -- added to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was my own fault. I was careless when setting up `iptables` and wrote `eth0` without checking the actual interface name which was `ens5` on that VPS. It's a stupid mistake that would not be worth mentioning, but there is a possibility that someone else may fall into this trap, so the answer applying this situation may help someone.